# Soft keyboard listener

Tags: java, android, keyboard, listener, andengine

I'm making a game using AndEngine which uses the soft keyboard of the device.

I'm NOT using `EditText`, but rather my own. I'm trying to detect presses on the soft keyboard,
I've already succeeded in showing and hiding the keyboard over the AndEngine scene.

My activity implements the `OnKeyboardActionListener`, which I read is used as a soft-keyboard listener, but I'm not sure how to register the keyboard with `this` class (the activity).
Obviously, at the moment, the code inside `onPress()` is useless..

I couldn't find any examples, most of them refers to `EditText`, which I'm not using..
Is it possible?
Maybe a service or something?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I'm trying to create my own keyboard using `KeyboardView` and a custom `Keyboard`,
This way I could do

```
KeyboardView kbView = new KeyboardView(this,null);
kbView.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(this, R.xml.keyboard);
kbView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(new OnKeyboardActionListener() {
    ....
}
```

Has anyone done this? works, doesn't?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your relevant part of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating my own `Keyboard` and `Keyboard`View`, then I used this code

```
CustomKeyboardView kbView = (CustomKeyboardView) findViewById(R.id.keyboard_view);
kbView.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(this, R.xml.myCustomKeyboard);
kbView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(new OnKeyboardActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
        // A Key was pressed
    }
    ....
}
```

And created a `KeyboardView` in the xml layout

```
<pathToCustomKeyboardView.CustomKeyboardView
    android:id="@+id/keyboard_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

`CustomKeyboardView` only extends `KeyboardView`, dunno why, but it works with the custom and not with the original

EDIT:
Also, The activity extends `SimpleLayoutGameActivity`, And then I selected the layout which contains the `CustomKeyboardView`